# Effect of combining features on classification

Tags: classification, feature-selection

I have 2 string features `F1` and `F2` based on which I am trying to perform classification. I have two choices, either to use the features individually, or to concatenate the two features to generate feature `F3` and then perform classification based on `F3` alone.

As an example, let us say that I am trying to classify a bigram. Should I divide the bigram into its constituent words and use them as features, or should I use the bigram itself.

```
Examples: w1w2, label
Model 1: Y1(w1,w2) = label
Model 2: Y2(w1+w2) = label
```

What are the pros and cons of each approach? Which is expected to work better?

Comment: Why not include both? It's equivalent to a traditional interaction model, y ~ a + b + a*b

Comment: @spin-glass If using both makes sense, that means that a+b and a*b are different. Please can you explain how they are different? My intuition is that they are exactly the same, except a+b will perform better because of bigram scarcity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your two strings are first and last names.  Your data looks like this:

```
label, firstname, lastname
1, 'Tom', 'Jones'
0, 'Bob', 'Dylan'
1, 'Bob', 'Jones'
```

Your bigram—or interaction term `firstname * lastname`—would be

```
label, ..., fullname
1, ..., 'Tom Jones'
0, ..., 'Bob Dylan'
1, ..., 'Bob Jones'
```

Now, when you run your classification algorithm, your data will need to take this form (usually the data format is automatically converted to this in your program, such as R):

```
label, Tom, Jones, Bob, Dylan, TomJones, BobDylan, BobJones
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Since we have more than one "Bob" (i.e. both "Bob Dylan" and "Bob Jones"), then the variable "Bob" is not perfectly correlated with "Bob Dylan".  Therefore, the classification algorithm is able to use the variation of "Bob", and "Bob Dylan" to predict the label.

However, "Tom" is perfectly correlated with "Tom Jones", since there are other people who have the first name "Tom" in the data.  Therefore, the classification algorithm cannot use both "Tom", and "Tom Jones".  Instead, it can only use one or the other.

Since you'd like to use all the available information you have (i.e. firstname, lastname *and* fullname), but you don't know which firstnames/lastnames are perfectly correlated with fullname, then you should use a ridge regression because this type of regression can deal with perfectly correlated independent variables.  Example code (in R) looks like this:

```
library(glmnet)
df <- read.csv(...)
X <- sparse.model.matrix(~firstname + lastname + firstname*lastname, df)
y <- df$label
fit <- cv.glmnet(X, y, family='binomial', alpha=0)
predictions <- predict(fit, X, type='response')
```

Comment: In your Bob Dylan and Bob Jones example,couldn't the algorithm just fall back on the last name, "Dylan", instead of the fullname, "Bob Dylan"? My question is if any information is added when we add the full-name feature to the first and last name features.

Comment: Yes, there is extra information.  Not with Dylan, but with Jones because there are examples where the last name is Jones but fullname is either Bob Jones or Tom Jones.

Comment: @sping-glass So what is the answer to my original question. Does adding a*b to and already existing feature set a+b help in any way? I guess the question can be generalized to, does adding a new feature which can be uniquely determined from existing features help?

Comment: Yes, adding a*b to a + b will improve the model, assuming the interaction effect a*b is important.  It's impossible to know that beforehand, but it is prudent to test that first to make sure.